# Simple JavaScript captcha using random array

Tags: javascript

I have created a simple Javascript Captcha but currently the values are randomly generated but I want to get values from the array only(want to randomized these two array), plz check my code I want to do this using simple Javascript with no dependency also plz fix the function validate().

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

function myCaptcha() {
var leftnum =[5, 10, 15, 20];
var rightnum =[2, 4, 6, 8];

var leftnum = Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
var rightnum = Math.floor(Math.random()*11);


var tolnum = leftnum + rightnum ;

document.getElementById("sh").innerHTML = leftnum + " + " + rightnum;

}

function validate() {
    var captchanow = document.getElementById("captcha");

    if (captchanow != "") {
    alert("Please enter a captcha");    
        return false;
    }
    else if(captchanow == tolnum) {
        alert("wrong captcha entered"); 
        return false;
    }
    else {
        form.submit
    }
    return true;

}

</script>
</head>

<body onload="myCaptcha()">

<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="return false;">
  <p>Captcha :
  <input name="captcha" type="text" id="captcha" value="" />

  <label id="sh" value=""></label></p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" onclick="validate()"/>
  </p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This isn't a "plz _[sic]_ fix my code" website.

Answer (score 1):

I discourage you strongly from using a JavaScript captcha as **it will entirely remove the point of a captcha, which is to not be machine-readable.**

Instead, I would recommend you to switch to something like [reCAPTCHA](http://www.google.com/recaptcha).

Using a JavaScript CAPTCHA will only upset your users and spambots may solve it with their eyes closed [figuratively].

Comment: Yes that's ryt but my question is not resolved, i want to get randon number from my array variables. Just consider this as a question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a Javascript CAPTCHA is completely pointless, as the bots that you want to stop won't be running the Javascript in the page.

Anyhow, this is how you pick items from arrays:

```
var leftnums =[5, 10, 15, 20];
var rightnums =[2, 4, 6, 8];

var leftnum = leftnums[Math.floor(Math.random() * leftnums.length)];
var rightnum = rightnums[Math.floor(Math.random() * rightnums.length)];
```

To get the value of the input field, use the `value` property:

```
var captchanow = document.getElementById("captcha").value;
```

To check if two numbers differ, use the `!=` operator, and parse the string to an integer value:

```
else if(parseInt(captchanow,10) != tolnum) {
```

Comment: Thanks I didn't find this "leftnums[Math.floor(Math.random() * leftnums.length)];" anywhere let me check

Comment: You wouldn't find it verbatim anywhere with your own, personal variable names in them. You can deduce it from base principles.

Comment: @user1167075: Sorry for the confusion; by "this is how you..." I didn't mean that your current code contains that, I meant that you can use the code to do it.